# Stuck with booting on Mac

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, single-user

Not able to login into my Mac. I have deleted some files earlier today and after that mac never starts and hangs in booting state.

I am to login to SINGLE USER MODE and I deleted the file /.AppleSetupDone and lot of steps I have followed.

Unique thing is I am getting whoami response as 0 and not able to switch to admin user. Strange part is I am getting -sh-3.2# as logged in user and not myself.

Any suggestions??
Macos Mojave
Files deleted - /usr/bin (Not sure exactly, I was following sone instructions)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) I know it can be frustrating when you're attempting to solve an issue, however it's vital that you provide us with sufficient details to assist you. As the question is written, it's impossible to tell exactly what caused this issue (beyond the strong likelihood that you deleted some files you shouldn't have). Can you please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/373972/edit) your question to clarify what you deleted, the version of macOS you're running, and the *lot of steps I have followed*. Otherwise we really don't have enough context to help you.

Comment: I have edited it and attached screenshot where I am in single user mode and not logged in as admin user..

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but since you're a little vague on what you actually did it'd be great if you could add a link to the instructions you followed. Also, have you got a Time Machine or other backup of your data?

Comment: Actually the problem is the macos startup disk is pointing to 10.14.5 which is not downloaded and installed fully...how it got pointing to 10.14.5 i am not sure, but is there a way to set os version back to Mojave using single mode terminal...

Comment: But macOS 10.14.x **is** macOS Mojave. It seems there's more going on here than you've explained. Do you have a backup? What model Mac is this? And do you have access to another Mac?

Comment: I am reinstalling it.. i couldn't handle it because lot of action items are pending one..Thanks a lot for listening and helping out. Much appreciated 

Comment: No worries. Feel free to come back and ask other questions if you run into any other issues. :)

Comment: Fwiw: You can’t su in single user mode because directory services isn’t started yet so the system doesn’t know about any normal users. You can manually start it and then it will work.